# How to retrive a report variable from java code, to check if report has no pages?

Tags: java, variables, jasper-reports

Could anyone explain how to retrieve the `REPORT_COUNT` variable value of a report from my java code?.

I need that value because I want to show my own message when report has no pages and I don't want to show empty viewer in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your asking how to get report variable and this is how:

```
//Create a base filler
JRBaseFiller filler = JRFiller.createFiller(DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance(),report);
//Fill the report
JasperPrint jasperPrint = filler.fill(map, connection);
//Get the variables / parameter from the filler
Object rc = filler.getVariableValue("REPORT_COUNT");
int count = 0;
if (rc instanceof Number){
  count = ((Number)rc).intValue();
}
```

**However**, the easiest way to check if you have pages is this:

Set the attribute `whenNoDataType="NoPages"` on the `jasperReport` tag in the `jrxml`. This attribute will ensure that empty report (0 pages) is returned if your datasource is empty. (see [whenNoDataType](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/WhenNoDataTypeEnum.html) attributes)

and in java.

```
//jasperPrint is the JasperPrint object retrieved after fill
List<JRPrintPage> pages = jasperPrint.getPages();
if (pages.size() == 0) {
    // No pages
}
```

Comment: Can you say whan `whenNoDataType="NoPages"` attribute does? Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza I have added clarification in post.